# difference between import commands

Tags: reactjs, import

What's the semantic difference between

```
import {
  FaceOutline as FaceIcon,
  Key as KeyIcon
} from '@iconify/icons-mdi';
```

and

```
import FaceIcon from '@iconify/icons-mdi/face-outline';
import KeyIcon from '@iconify-icons/mdi/key';
```

While the latter one works, the first one doesn't.
The error message says, that `@iconify/icons-mdi` is not found?!
`

Btw: Other packages are fine with that. Example:

```
import {
  Menu as MenuIcon,
  ChevronRight as ChevronRightIcon
} from '@material-ui/icons';
```

Comment: The difference is in the export. The second one works, so the exports are named `FaceIcon` and `KeyIcon` while in the first one you are trying to import `FaceOutline` and  `Key` - you need to revers the 'as` bindings like this: `FaceIcon as FaceOutline, KeyIcon as Key`

Comment: Also are those import paths correct? You have slashes and dashes at different points in the from path? It looks like `@iconify/icons-mdi` is the correct one. Also are you sure that's the exact error message? Usually the message is something more like "module X does not contain export Y" or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the modules are exported.

In the `@material-ui` example, there will be an `index.js` file located at the root containing named exports for other files. This isn't a requirement, so not all packages let you do this.

Take a look at the material-ui source code. You can see [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui-icons/src/index.js) that this file exports all of the icons using named exports.

However, if you go to a [specific icon module](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui-icons/src/AccessAlarm.js), you will see it uses a default export.

This is why you can do it more than one way.

As for the `@iconify/icons-mdi`, I do not know if they contain this index file, so you may or may not be able to import both ways. I don't have experience with this library like I do with material-ui, but the documentation I found did not reference named imports anywhere.

You can read more about the differences between named and default imports in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what and how library is exporting.

If the library uses `named` exports, then you can use this syntax:

```js
import { some } from 'some;'
```

If the module exports only the `default` exports, you will have to use the following entry:

```js
import some from 'some;'
```

To better understand this topic, I suggest you read the [following article](http://www.thedreaming.org/2017/04/28/es6-imports-babel/)